# Couldn't validate TLS certificate - Nord VPN

Tags: tls, vpn, firewalls, tls-intercept

[image]

I received this notification from Nord randomly. Should I be worried? Is there something I can do? Am I being hacked?

P.S. clicked Don't trust

EDIT: I tried connecting from mobile data and am receiving a different notification, so the ISP/router is not the problem.

[image]

Comment: Being that `issued by` and `issued to` are the same, this is a self-signed certificate.  Nord uses certificates that are signed by recognized CA's (see https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/1047409912/Nordvpn-com-is-telling-me-Invalid-security-certificate.htm).  So, this is not a true and correct certificate for Nord.  Is it possible that you are using a antivirus of security software, that is MITM'ing the connection to the VPN by design?

Comment: @mti2935 I don't have any antivirus, just windows defender

Comment: In that case, I would be concerned.  Is it possible for you to try connecting to Nord's VPN service using a different connection, and if so, do you see the same certificate in that case?

Comment: Good call I, tried using mobile data and am getting a different warning

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show the different warning that you get when you connect through the different connection?

Comment: Thank you.  So, you are seeing another self-signed certificate, when you connect to Nord through a different connection.  The fact that you are seeing the same behavior through two disparate connections would seem to suggest that it might be your device that is compromised, not the connection.  As another test, to confirm, you might want to try connecting to Nord from a different device through both connections, and see if you are getting correct certificates for Nord when doing so.